# Where should I put the StoreBillingDetailsToMonthlyTable() to successfully execute it? I've tried putting it in Form Load, Timer and Paid Button

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Where should I put the StoreBillingDetailsToMonthlyTable() to successfully execute it? I've tried putting it in Form Load, Timer and Paid Button but it does not execute and no changes are being done in the monthly table. I'm a beginner at this and I already ran out of ideas where to put and execute it. Have I committed any mistake on the coding or only the placing of the function is wrong?

```
 Private Sub Bills_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection()
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; userid=root; password=root; database=isp_database"
        MysqlConn.Open()

        Dim Query As String
        Query = "SELECT * FROM isp_database.bill_table"
        Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Clear()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        'DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing

        Using da As New MySqlDataAdapter(Command)
            da.Fill(dt)
            previousRowCount = dt.Rows.Count
        End Using
        Display_Table()
        StoreBillingDetailsToMonthlyTable()
        UpdateStatusToUnpaid()
        UpdateDateDue()

        MysqlConn.Close()

        Timer1.Enabled = True
        ' Set Timer interval (24 hours)
        timer = New Timer()
        timer.Interval = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ' milliseconds
        AddHandler timer.Tick, AddressOf Timer1_Tick
        timer.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Function CheckForNewData() As Boolean
        Dim MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection()
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; userid=root; password=root; database=isp_database"
        MysqlConn.Open()

        Dim Query As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM isp_database.bill_table"
        Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Clear()
        Using da As New MySqlDataAdapter(Command)
            da.Fill(dt)
        End Using

        Dim currentRowCount As Integer = dt.Rows(0)(0)

        If currentRowCount > previousRowCount Then
            previousRowCount = currentRowCount
            Return True
        End If

        Return False
        MysqlConn.Close()
    End Function

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        date_txt.Text = Date.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
        ' Check if new data has been inserted
        If CheckForNewData() Then
            UpdateStatusToUnpaid()
            UpdateDateDue()
        End If

        CheckUnpaidCustomers()

        StoreBillingDetailsToMonthlyTable()

        ' Reset the timer
        timer.Stop()
        timer.Start()
    End Sub


    Public Sub CheckUnpaidCustomers()
        Dim MysqlConn1 As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection()
        Dim MysqlConn2 As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection()
        Dim selectCommand As MySqlCommand
        Dim updateCommand As MySqlCommand
        Dim READER As MySqlDataReader

        MysqlConn1.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; userid=root; password=root; database=isp_database; "
        MysqlConn2.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; userid=root; password=root; database=isp_database; "

        ' Get current date
        Dim currentDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now

        ' Calculate due date as 28th day of the current month
        Dim dueDate As DateTime = New DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, 28)

        MysqlConn1.Open()
        MysqlConn2.Open()

        ' Create SQL SELECT statement
        Dim selectQuery As String = "SELECT client_id, amount, date_due FROM isp_database.bill_table WHERE status = 'UNPAID'"

        ' Create command object
        selectCommand = New MySqlCommand(selectQuery, MysqlConn1)
        selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date_due", dueDate)

        ' Execute the SELECT statement
        READER = selectCommand.ExecuteReader()

        ' Iterate through the records
        While READER.Read()
            Dim cid As Integer = READER("client_id")

            Dim amount As Decimal = 0 ' Initialize amount to a default value

            If Not Convert.IsDBNull(READER("amount")) Then
                amount = Convert.ToDecimal(READER("amount"))
            End If

            ' Calculate penalty amount
            Dim penaltyAmount As Decimal = amount * 0.2


            ' Create SQL UPDATE statement without due date
            Dim updateQuery As String = "UPDATE isp_database.bill_table SET status = 'UNPAID', penalty = @penalty WHERE client_id = @client_id"

            ' Create command object
            updateCommand = New MySqlCommand(updateQuery, MysqlConn2)
            updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@penalty", penaltyAmount)
            updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@client_id", cid)

            ' Execute the UPDATE statement
            updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End While

        ' Close the reader and the database connections
        READER.Close()
        MysqlConn1.Close()
        MysqlConn2.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateStatusToUnpaid()
        Dim Conn1 As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection()
        Conn1.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; userid=root; password=root; database=isp_database; "
        Conn1.Open()
        Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "UPDATE isp_database.bill_table SET Status = 'UNPAID' where date=NULL"
        Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, Conn1)
        READER = Command.ExecuteReader()
        READER.Close()
        Conn1.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateDateDue()
        Dim Conn2 As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection()
        Conn2.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; userid=root; password=root; database=isp_database; "
        Conn2.Open()
        Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
        Dim currentDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        Dim dueDate As DateTime = New DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, 28)
        Dim due As String = dueDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") ' Convert to yyyy-MM-dd format
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "UPDATE isp_database.bill_table SET date_due = '" & due & "'"
        Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, Conn2)
        READER = Command.ExecuteReader()
        Conn2.Close()
    End Sub

    Public Sub StoreBillingDetailsToMonthlyTable()
        Dim Conn1 As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection()
        Conn1.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; userid=root; password=root; database=isp_database;"

        ' Open the connection
        Conn1.Open()

        ' Retrieve billing details from the bill table
        Dim selectQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM isp_database.bill_table"
        Dim selectCommand As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(selectQuery, Conn1)
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader()

        ' Get the current month and year
        Dim currentDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        Dim currentMonth As Integer = currentDate.Month
        Dim monthName As String = currentDate.ToString("MMMM")
        Dim currentYear As Integer = currentDate.Year

        ' Iterate through the billing details
        While reader.Read()

            Dim client_id As Integer = CInt(reader("client_id"))
            Dim bill_no As Integer = CInt(reader("bill_id"))
            Dim amount_paid As Decimal = If(reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("amount")), 0, CDec(reader("amount")))

            If reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("date")) Then
                ' Handle DBNull case
                Dim date_paid As DateTime = DateTime.MinValue ' or any default value you prefer
            Else
                ' Convert the 'date' value to DateTime
                Dim date_paid As DateTime = CDate(reader("date"))


                ' Get the month and year from the billing date
                Dim billingMonth As Integer = date_paid.Month
                Dim billingYear As Integer = date_paid.Year

                ' Check if the billing date is in the current month and year
                If billingMonth = currentMonth AndAlso billingYear = currentYear Then
                    ' Insert billing details into the monthly table
                    Dim insertQuery As String = "INSERT INTO isp_database.monthly_table (month_name, bill_no, client_id, amount_paid, date_paid) VALUES (@bill_no, @client_id, @amount_paid, @date_paid)"
                    Dim insertCommand As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(insertQuery, Conn1)

                    ' Add parameters to the insert command
                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@month_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = monthName
                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@bill_no", SqlDbType.Int).Value = bill_no
                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@client_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = client_id
                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@amount_paid", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = amount_paid
                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@date_paid", SqlDbType.Date).Value = date_paid

                    ' Execute the insert command
                    insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

                End If
            End If
        End While

        ' Close the reader and connection
        reader.Close()
        Conn1.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles paid_btn.Click
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection()
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; userid=root; password=root; database=isp_database"
        Dim READER As MySqlDataReader

        Try
            MysqlConn.Open()

            Dim inDate As DateTime = DateTimePicker1.Value ' Get selected date from DateTimePicker
            Dim inDateStr As String = inDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") ' Convert to yyyy-MM-dd format
            Dim Query As String

            Query = "update isp_database.bill_table set status= 'PAID', connection='CONNECTED', penalty=NULL, date= '" & inDateStr & "' where client_id= '" & cid_tb.Text & "'"
            Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
            READER = Command.ExecuteReader
            Dim cid As String = cid_tb.Text.ToString()
            MessageBox.Show("CUSTOMER " & cid & " PAID!")



            MysqlConn.Close()

            Display_Table()

        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            cid_tb.Text = ""
            name_tb.Text = ""
            plan_tb.Text = ""
            price_tb.Text = ""

        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub Display_Table()
        Try
            Dim Str As String
            Str = "select * from isp_database.bill_table"
            MysqlConn.Open()
            Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(Str, MysqlConn)
            Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            dt.Clear()
            da.Fill(dt)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
            MysqlConn.Close()


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Comment: why are you mixing parameters and string concatenated sql statements, use only those with parameters, also Make A `INSERt INTO monthly_table  SELECT ...FROM bill_table WHERE date = curren_month`

Comment: Incidentally: 1) Each SQL connection object needs to be disposed of as sooon as you've finished using it, so add a `Finally` part to the Try...Catch statements and put `MysqlConn.Dispose()` in it. 2) It would be better to put the `timer.Stop()` line as the first line of the tick event handler so that if the code inside takes a while, there isn't another tick event raised.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Have you tried running it in the debugger, setting a breakpoint, and stepping through the code?  That might help you find where the behavior is not conforming to your expectations.

Comment: You are look at this the wrong way and that's making it harder to solve the problem. Don't just throw mud at the wall and hope something sticks. Logic first, then code. You should start by asking yourself when or under what circumstances you want the code executed. Once you know what it is that happens in the app that should trigger the execution of your code, you can then find out what event is raised under those circumstances. The fact that you've used `Load`, `Tick` and `Click` events so far shows that you have not put this kind of thought into it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I want it to execute everytime it detect changes in my table that is why I've tried to run a CheckForNewData in the tick and then put StoreBillingDetails inside the if else statement but it doesn't execute and no changes are being stored in the monthly table that is why I've tried putting it everywhere. I get no errors in the code, the only problem I get is that it doesn't successfully execute like what I expect it to.